# How to remove any sub array and keep only two top levels of a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I need to modify an array with subarrays and keep only the top two arrays (array -> results - x) and remove any subarray below. For example array "location" & "syncState" should be removed.

Original array:

```
$device_array = [
    "totalCount" => "3",
    "results" => [
        [
            "id" => "2",
            "serialNumber" => "DX",
            "location" => ["id" => "5", "locationName" => "US"]
        ],
        [
            "id" => "4",
            "serialNumber" => "DM",
            "syncState" => ["id" => "7", "locationName" => "DE"]
        ],
        [
            "id" => "5",
            "serialNumber" => "C0"
        ]
    ]
];
```

The array should look like this:

```
Array
(
    [totalCount] => 3
    [results] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [serialNumber] => DX
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4
                    [serialNumber] => DM
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 5
                    [serialNumber] => C0
                )
        )
)
```

I'm trying to loop through the arrays (sub arrays included) but I can't remove all of the subarrays that sit under `$device_array['results'][x]`.

```
foreach ($device_array as $key => $value) {
    if(is_array($value)) {
        unset($device_array['results'][0]['location']);
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like a perfect exercise to learn some TDD. Please share more details about your attempts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just loop the `results` subarray directly and write a custom filter which will modify each entry by reference.  Any of the associative elements that hold array type data will be filtered out.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/2JviE))

```
$array = [
    "totalCount" => "3",
    "results" => [
        [
            "id" => "2",
            "serialNumber" => "DX",
            "location" => ["id" => "5", "locationName" => "US"]
        ],
        [
            "id" => "4",
            "serialNumber" => "DM",
            "syncState" => ["id" => "7", "locationName" => "DE"]
        ],
        [
            "id" => "5",
            "serialNumber" => "C0"
        ]
    ]
];

foreach ($array['results'] as &$entry) {
    $entry = array_filter($entry, 'is_scalar');
}

var_export($array);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'totalCount' => '3',
  'results' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'id' => '2',
      'serialNumber' => 'DX',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'id' => '4',
      'serialNumber' => 'DM',
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      'id' => '5',
      'serialNumber' => 'C0',
    ),
  ),
)
```

---

Or completely functional style: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/kP24g))

```
$array['results'] = array_map(
    function($entry) {
        return array_filter($entry, 'is_scalar');
    },
    $array['results']
);

var_export($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you obtain the output, but I am not so sure if this is what you need in your case

```
<?php
 $array = [
'total' => 2,                 
'result' => [
        [
            'id' => 1,
            'serialNumber' => 'DX',
            'location' => ['id'=>1, 'locationName'=>'US']
            
        ],
        [
            'id' => 2 ,
            'serialNumber' => 'DO',
            'syncState' => ['id'=>7, 'locationName'=>'DE']
            
        ]
    ]
];
      foreach( $array['result'] as $key => $value ){
        foreach($value as $key2=>$subarray){
           if(is_array($subarray)){
             unset($value[$key2]);
           }
         }
        $array['result'][$key] = $value;
      }

      print_r($array);
```

Comment: Hi Alexandru, the array you composed is a bit different then the I one I posted. Should be $array[results][0][location] looks like on your example a sub array is missing between "results" and the one I would like to remove "location"